# My gdb debugger isn't responding when I launch it

Tags: c++, debugging, terminal, gdb

I tried to setup the gdb debugger today which was already a hassle in itself. Now that it works (I can launch it at least) it gets stuck none of my commands have any effect on the debugger. I launch the debugger like so:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp -g
$ gdb ./a.out
```

I can run `layout next` when I type `run` it just doesn't respond anymore.

[image]

I put an infinite loop in my program on purpose to see simulate a bug. Even without the loop its the exact same behavior.

It also doesn't say "done" when reading in the compiled file:

[image: This is what it says when I launch it]

Now when I try to start *gdb* without any files specified. This is what happens:

```sh
➜ gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) file ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
Reading symbols from /Users/Documents/coding/C++/testing_c++/testing_c++/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out...
../../gdb/thread.c:95: internal-error: struct thread_info *inferior_thread(): Assertion `current_thread_ != nullptr' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) y

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

../../gdb/thread.c:95: internal-error: struct thread_info *inferior_thread(): Assertion `current_thread_ != nullptr' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) n
```

Comment: If you put an infinite loop in your program, how do you expect it to trap a signal nicely? You broke it!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But it's not the program that should trap signals when running in a debugger, it's the debugger that should. And it should definitely react to `Ctrl-C`. Not to mention that even when not running in a debugger, the OS should react to the signal sent by `Ctrl-C` and kill the process (default behavior for `SIGINT`).

Comment: @Phil Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need semicolons after block-statements (the curly-braced `{}`blocks). Which is good since you "forget" that semicolon in some places.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes thank you that should've just been a testing program to see how the debugger works. But you also don't know do you?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, the debugger *should* catch the `SIGINT` signal generated by `Ctrl-C`. Unless perhaps the shell or terminal swallows it somehow? How do your shell/terminal configuration look like? Also, what happens if you press e.g, `Ctrl-Z` to pause the running foreground process? Do you get back to GDB then? Or to the shell? Or does nothing happen then either?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Still nothing

Comment: Good research! You should probably do what the message tells you to do: Report it as an issue to the GDB maintainers. And generate the core file to provide with the bug report.